# scrapy unable to extract some data from website

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am using scrapy to crawl a page, I am able to get all the simple things that are visible text. However there are some texts that are not visible to the crawler and end up showing as spaces.

For instance seeing page sources allow me to see these fields:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f056mffmuah6uu4/Screenshot%202015-07-23%2018.23.32.png?dl=0

I've tried numerous times to access this field through xpath and css and was not able to get these fields after each attempt.

When I try something like:

```
response.xpath('//text()').extract()
```

I am not able to see these fields in the text dump at all.

Would anyone have an idea as to why these fields are not visible to scrapy? The website is: https://www.buzzbuzzhome.com/uc/units/houses/sapphire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your spider, you need to make an *additional XHR POST request* to `https://www.buzzbuzzhome.com/bbhAjax/Development/UnitPriceHistory` endpoint to get the price history providing necessary headers and POST parameters:

```
import json
import scrapy


class BuzzSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'buzzbuzzhome'
    allowed_domains = ['buzzbuzzhome.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.buzzbuzzhome.com/uc/units/houses/sapphire']

    def parse(self, response):
        unit_id = response.xpath("//div[@id = 'unitDetails']/@data-unit-id").extract()[0]
        development_url = "uc"
        new_relic_id = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'xpid')]").re(r'xpid:"(.*?)"')

        params = {"developmentUrl": development_url, "unitID": unit_id}
        yield scrapy.Request("https://www.buzzbuzzhome.com/bbhAjax/Development/UnitPriceHistory",
                             method="POST",
                             body=json.dumps(params),
                             callback=self.parse_history,
                             headers={
                                 "Accept": "*/*",
                                 "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36",
                                 "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                                 "X-NewRelic-ID": new_relic_id,
                                 "Origin": "https://www.buzzbuzzhome.com",
                                 "Host": "www.buzzbuzzhome.com",
                                 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
                             })

    def parse_history(self, response):
        for row in response.css("div.row"):
            title = row.xpath(".//div[@class='content-title']/text()").extract()[0].strip()
            text = row.xpath(".//div[@class='content-text']/text()").extract()[0].strip()

            print title, text
```

Prints:

```
05/25/2015 Unit listed as Sold
12/18/2014 Unit listed as For Sale
11/24/2014 Unit price increased  by 1.54% to $461,990
11/04/2014 Unit price increased  by 6.81% to $454,990
10/02/2014 Unit price increased  by 4.67% to $425,990
01/22/2014 Unit price increased  by 2.52% to $406,990
12/06/2013 Unit listed as For Sale at $396,990
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you please help me understand why the need for the second request? Thanks again

Comment: @rmaka sure! Open up browser developer tools, network tab and see how much is involved in building the page in the browser. For this particular page, there are several XHR requests sent. One of them to get the history which we've simulated in the Scrapy spider.